# How to hide layouts / views programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have just started learning Android. Few confusions I have regarding layouts in XML

1. Are all views that I define in my layout are essentially inflated or they are optional? Suppose I have two different views in a view-group but I want to 
   use only first or only second conditionally. Is it possible?
2. How dynamically created views deal with layout.XML
   file?
3. If I want received messages to be shown in red and sent messages in black how can I do that?

Answer (score 12):

You can include views in the XML layout file that are invisible until you programatically display them. Just use "android:visible="gone" or "android:visible="invisible" in the XML file.

For instance, I include the following in my layout file initially but it's not visible:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pnlLatLong"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblLatLng"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lat_long"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtLatitude"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
            />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtLongitude"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

In Java code, when the code logic dictates it should be visible, I change the visibility programatically to:

```
    View v = findViewById(R.id.pnlLatLng);
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: It is important to note that INVISIBLE and GONE are not synonyms. GONE will practically remove the view from the layout, adjusting other views as needed, while INVISIBLE will simply hide the view, but not change its bounds / rendered size.

Answer (score 1):

you can set android:visibility="gone" in xml or by code setVisibility(View.gone); for change text color you can set android:text color="#000000" or by code setTextColor();